# Parsing nginx log data with whitespace as delimiter

Tags: python, nginx, logparser

I am trying to parse the following format from a nginx log file:

```
10.0.0.1    [02/Oct/2012:10:21:46 +0000]    GET /api/123/test.json?stop=2012-09-29  502 0
```

My python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

f = file('slow-queries.txt', 'r')

# iterate over the lines in the file
for line in f:
    # split the line into a list of column values
    columns = line.split(' ')
    # clean any whitespace off the items
    # columns = [col.strip() for col in columns]

    # ensure the column has at least one value before printing
    if columns:
        print "first  =>", columns[0]  # print the first column
        print "second =>", columns[1]
```

Basically all I want from the log file is the query that was sent, so in the above example, i'm looking to extract `/api/123/test.json?stop=2012-09-29`

My script doesn't seem to do this, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are tabs, not spaces:

```
ip, date, method, path, status, _ = line.split('\t')
```

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing wrong is using a general purpose programming language where a specialized log file parser language is available: awk ;)

```
awk '{ print $5 }' /path/to/slow-queries.txt
```

Of course its possible with python/php/perl/YOUR AD HERE/ but awk will always out perform them ^^

EDIT:
Maybe even pipe the results to a new file which will then be used by your python scripts:

```
awk '{ print $5 }' /path/to/slow-queries.txt > /tmp/queries.txt
```